# Need Help with a custom Setting

Tags: class, customsetting, checkbox

i have a custom setting with a field type "checkbox" set to true but if i try to query it on a class it's allways returning false, i don't know why.

```
Email_Engine__c ee = Email_Engine__c.getInstance();
    system.debug(ee.Turned_On__c);
    if(ee.Turn_On__c == true){...
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind posting how your custom setting is configured? May be a screenshot will help here.

Comment: Do you have multiple levels configured (user, profile)? Only the lowest level setting is returned.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the records created by clicking on 'Manage' button.
It will look something similar like this.
This is returning the exact value for the corresponding record.

Email_Engine__c ee = Email_Engine__c .getInstance('the record name you want to look for');
system.debug(ee.Turned_On__c);

Comment: If he doesn't have any record for this custom setting then this line `ee.Turned_On__c` should throw null pointer exception.